# Use of Expression in LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq

I have an `Expression` which could be any value. For example it could be `() => 5 + 5`. How would I use that `Expression` to search a `List<int>` to return `true` if the value is found in the `List<int>`? What I'm trying to do is I'm given an Expression and I'm checking a list to see if the value of the Expression is in the list

```
    private int FindRecord(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression expression)
    {
        // expression when stepping through in debug is {() => 5 + 5}
        List<int> list = new List<int>();

        list.Add(5);
        list.Add(10);

        return list.Any(expression); // syntax issue - cannot convert from Expression to Func<int,bool>
    }
```

Comment: Why isn't it an `Expression<Func<int>>` or really just a `Func<int>`

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Your expression is returning an integer (so cannot be used in a `Àny` method). And since your method is also returning an integer the `Any` cannot be returned.

Comment: @Arcord I'm given an Expression and I'm checking a list to see if the value of the Expression is in the list

Answer (score 0):

EDIT : I misunderstood the question so here is my new answer:

```
    private bool FindRecord(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<int>> expression)
    {
        int valueToSearch = expression.Compile()();

        List<int> list = new List<int>();

        list.Add(5);
        list.Add(10);

        return list.Any(i => i == valueToSearch); // syntax issue - cannot convert from Expression to Func<int,bool>
    }
```

- The return type of you function should be a "bool" (Any return a bool, not an int).
- Parameter type "Expression" is not accurate enough, you should say it's a expression of a function return an integer.
- You need to compile this expression to be able to "run" it and to get the actual value.

Comment: This would require them to pass `x => x == 5 + 5` instead of `() => 5 + 5`

Comment: That's a good point. So now I'm not sure what he want to do here...

Comment: I reread the question and fix my answer, thank you :-)

Comment: How would I cast my Expression to Expression<Func<int>>?

Comment: `FindRecord((Expression<Func<int>>) expression)` should work if the expression is indeed a `Expression<Func<int>>` but according to what you saw while debugging I think it will be the case. If not you should show us more info (like how you get/build the expression or the expression type).

Answer (score 0):

Well, you *can* do it as follows without `Compile()` on the Expression parameter, but it's really not a good idea. You generally don't want to be passing `Expression` around in your code as it will fail at runtime instead of compile time. You should change your method to accept an Expression of the expected type instead, or make it generic.

```
private static bool FindRecord(Expression expression, IEnumerable<int> list)
{
    ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), "x");
    Expression body = Expression.Equal(parameter, Expression.Invoke(expression));
    Expression<Func<int, bool>> lambda = (Expression<Func<int, bool>>)Expression.Lambda(body, parameter);
        
    Console.WriteLine(lambda);
    return list.Any(lambda.Compile());
}
```